# How to decode event data "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002"

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs

I got "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002" which is "id" from event in the code below.

And, I want to decode "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002" to string or number.

Do you know how to do that?

```js
  const data = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt("txHash")

  const data1 = await web3.eth.abi.decodeLog([
    {
      type: 'uint256',
      name: 'id',
      indexed: true,
    },{
      type: 'string',
      name: 'name',
    }
  ],
  data.logs[0].data,
  data.logs[0].topics
  );

Result {
  '1': 'name',
  '4': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002',
  __length__: 2,
  name: 'name',
  id: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002` is a string that is encoding a number in a hexadecimal system. You can turn it into an integer using `parseInt(hexString, 16);` where `hexString` is the string that you want to decode, and 16 is the base number system  (hexadecimal).

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your advice!